# Unspecified value parameter rconv

Tags: scala, slick

I had these lines in my code

```
val x = database.withSession { implicit session => 
  StaticQuery.queryNA[Long](s"select id from .....")
}

val y = database.withSession { implicit session => 
  StaticQuery.queryNA[Long](s"select id1 from .....")
}

val z = database.withSession { implicit session => 
  StaticQuery.queryNA[(Long, Long)](s"select id1, id2 from .....")
}
```

In order to minimize code duplication I changed my code to

```
def genericExec[T](query: String) : List[T] = {
  database.withSession { implicit session => 
    StaticQuery.queryNA[T](query).list
  }
}

for {
  x <- genericExec[Long](query1)
  y <- genericExec[Long](query2)
  z <- genericExec[(Long, Long)](query3)
} {...}
```

Of course I get an error now that

```
Error:(16, 32) not enough arguments for method queryNA: (implicit rconv: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[T])scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery[Unit,T].
Unspecified value parameter rconv.
         StaticQuery.queryNA[T](query).list
```

Since the type T is totally generic its impossible for me to provide all types of conversions. So how can I keep my generic implementation and just provide the conversions which my type T is actually using in my code (aka Long, and (Long, Long)

Answer (score 0):

Because `queryNA` has a `GetResult` constraint on `T`, your function has to have the same constraint. You need to tell your generic method that it is only valid for types `T` that have a `GetResult` defined, so:

```
def genericExec[T : GetResult](query: String) : List[T] = ...
```

or equivalently:

```
def genericExec[T](query: String)(implicit rconv: GetResult[T]) : List[T] = ...
```